# When is it appropriate to release CGImageRef?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, uiimage, cgimage, cgimageref

When `XCode` analyzes my code, it finds potential memory leaks. I use `ARC`, but I learned that ARC doesn't handle C types. Since I use `CGImageRef` in order to create `UIImage` with it and assign to `UIImageView.image` property, When is it appropriate to release `CGImageRef`? Can I release it right after I create a new `UIImage` with it? If I release the `CGImageRef`, then does it make my `UIImage` instance also invalid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIImageView retains the image property (if it needs it) or it copies it - whatever. Once you have set that property, you can then immediately release the CGImageRef.